# Executing Dijkstra's algorithm starting at 1 to this graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

I tried to apply Dijkstra's algorithm to this graph; however, the end result after completing the table and updating the shortest path consistently was $(1,2,5,6)$. But when I went to the tutor a week ago, we concluded that the correct answer was $(1,2,3,5,6)$; I didn't quite understand how he got that result. Therefore, which one of the answers is correct, and most importantly why?

[image]

Comment: The correct answer to what question?

Comment: The shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: From 1 to 6????

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning that, will edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1,2,5,6)$ is correct. Applying the algorithm:

- Shortest path from 1 to 2 has cost 2
- From 1 to 4: 4
- From 1 to 2 to 5: 4
- From 1 to 2 to 4: 6
- **From 1 to 2 to 5 to 6: 6**

Comment: Thank you very much, I still have no idea why or how he got the {1,2,3,5} answer.

Comment: @S.Riyadh He messed up, that's all!

Comment: @S.Riyadh Also, please accept this answer.

Comment: Just did, was waiting for the timer to run off. Thank you very much for your help